# Position Text Mesh above parent transform in world space

Tags: unity, transformation, coordinates

I'm making an isometric-ish 2d game in Unity. I want to display text above a sprite during certain conditions. For this, I'm using a TextMesh instantiated as a child of the sprite.

In local space, this obviously means that when I rotate a sprite, its children rotate along with it. From the player's perspective, the label now appears to the side of the sprite, rather than staying above it.

I can always calculate the world space position of the TextMesh during LateUpdate(), but a) that solution requires a designer to know that a script will alter the local transform, and b) things built into Unity have more eyeballs on them, so I'd rather use that.

Is there a mechanism built into Unity such that I can set a child's transform in the inspector to e.g. `position.y = 0.4` and have it render 0.4 units above the parent in *world* space? Edit: Additionally, I want it to follow the parent as it moves, so just calculating once on `Instantiate()` isn't quite what I want either.

Comment: In the inspector? No. You'd have to write a custom script.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the confirmation. Would using UI text to accomplish this work, or is this TextMesh with script approach my best bet?

Comment: UI text would probably be just as awkward. Just create a script with a public `Vector3` that it uses to update the position of its game object.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create your own component to do this

Create a MonoBehaviour component script that exposes a public `Vector3` that is then used to update the position of the object in WorldSpace instead of local.

Comment: Thanks! I went with code that copies the `transform.position` to a private member variable on `Awake()` so that a designer can use the inspector to set the values without the script overwriting them.